# Setting background size in css to 100% results in poor print quality (pixelation)

Tags: css, printing

My report screen consists of DIVs with background images that are adjusted using:

```
   background-size: 100% auto;
```

When printing the page (via Chrome 53) the images are pixelated. If I use an **img** element all is good. Any idea how to set it right? Do I have to use an img element to have a proper printing quality?

JSBin with background-image div:
https://jsbin.com/royufibeko/edit?output

JSBin with img element:
https://jsbin.com/zulocideri/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Have you tried putting your print styles in a separate stylesheet?

Comment: To what purpose? Should there be a rendering difference when printed?

Comment: Could be a glitch within the browser you're using. Try using a stylesheet that is specific to printing with your current styles copied into it and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Wait when you say printing the page do you mean they are pixelated on the print preview page or the actual printout?

Comment: Probably obvious- but are you using a large enough image? Setting background-size that way will enlarge a small image which would make it pixelated.

Comment: @kthornbloom As seen on the JSBin https://jsbin.com/royufibeko/edit?output The image looks good on screen but pixelated upon printing

Comment: @JesseElser on actual printout

Comment: The problem for me was setting `filter: grayscale(100%);` on the `body` element. Which caused the pixelated print in the preview and on the printout. Maybe this helps others looking for this solution.